# Stream collect method

Tags: java

I do not want create new list from Stream.collect method in second time. It should add in previous list only. I am trying to do like below but it is not working.
As per document, Collectors.toList() is always create new list, and collect() method is not allowing old list. Is there any way i can reuse my previous list(listA) in second time.

```
List<A> listA = xList.stream().map().collect(Collectors.toList());
                 yList.stream().map().collect(**listA**);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.collect`, write `.forEach(listA::add)`.

(Technically, you should also replace `Collectors.toList()` in the first example with `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, because `toList()` does not guarantee that it returns a mutable list.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish it.  Here are two.  They are very similar.

- The first simply flattens the two lists supplied directly.
- The second concatenates two streams together.

```
List<A> list = Stream.of(xList, yList).flatMap(List::stream)
     .map(<someFnc>)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<A> list2 = Stream.concat(xList.stream().map(<someFnc>), 
      yList.stream().map(<someFnc>)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
List<A> listA = xList.stream().map().collect(Collectors.toList());    
yList.stream().map().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> listA));
```

EDIT :
`collect` method takes a `Collector` and internally `Collectors.toCollection` adds yList element to the original list as -

```
Collector<T, ?, C> toCollection(Supplier<C> collectionFactory) {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(collectionFactory, Collection<T>::add,
                               (r1, r2) -> { r1.addAll(r2); return r1; },
                               CH_ID);
}
```

Comment: Can the downvoters explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: *I do not want create new list from Stream.collect method in second time* If I had to guess I would say that it is because it does not  combine the lists into one without using a second stream statement and collection, as required in the question.

Comment: _I do not want create new list from Stream.collect method in second time_ and `yList.stream().map().collect(**listA**)` - implies `yList` needs to be appended to `listA`

Comment: @Pankaj  You may be correct, I don't really know.  I agree the question is somewhat ambiguous and thus could be interpreted differently.

Comment: Read the Javadoc of `newCollection`: `collectionFactory` - a `Supplier` which returns a new, _**empty**_ `Collection` of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-).

```
List<A> listA = Stream.concat(xList.stream().map(), yList.stream().map())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```